# React-hook-form image handling problems

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I am using react-hook-form for my application and came into the following problem.

I initialize the defaultValues like so

```
const {register, submit } = useForm({
   defaultValues : {
     image: null
}
})
```

The input where I upload an image is this

```
<label htmlFor="image">
      <span className="mt-2 text-base leading-normal">
         Upload an image
      </span>
      <input
        {...register("image")}
        type="file"
        accept="image/*"
        className="hidden"
        />
</label>
```

When I submit this form, the image is still null, instead of a FileList like this:

[image]

Does the error have something to do with the "null" value I declare for the image on the defaultValues? If so, what is the correct value for image handling using react-hook-form?

Comment: You could add to the question information that react-hook-form is a library with a link to it. I didn't know, for instance :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a *onChange* props to your input, as such :

```
onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent) => {e.target.files[0]}}
```